# Dojo 1.8: Getting dest.appendChild is not a function while rendering a custom template

Tags: templates, widget, dojo

After adding in the WidgetsInTemplateMixin, I am receiving an error

```
dest.appendChild is not a function
```

In the documentation, it claims that there will be an error if this.containerNode is not able to contain any child objects. However, I have marked the containerNode attachment point for a div with dojo type "dijit/layout/ContentPane". Can anyone explain to me why this isn't working?

Here is the Template file

```
<div class="${baseClass}">
    <div class="${baseClass}Container"
         data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer"
         data-dojo-props="design: 'headline'">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
             data-dojo-props="region: 'top'">
            Top
        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
             data-dojo-props="region: 'center'"
             data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">
        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
             data-dojo-props="region: 'leading', splitter: true">
            Sidebar
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript definition

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_OnDijitClickMixin",
    "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
    "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
    "dijit/layout/TabContainer",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
    "dojo/text!./templates/MainContainer.html"
], function (declare,
             _WidgetBase,
             _OnDijitClickMixin,
             BorderContainer,
             ContentPane,
             TabContainer,
             _TemplatedMixin,
             _WidgetsInTemplateMixin,
             template)
{

    return declare([_WidgetBase, _OnDijitClickMixin, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {

        templateString:template,
        baseClass:"main"
    });

});
```

The custom widget defined declaratively

```
<div data-dojo-type="main/ui/MainContainer" data-dojo-props="title: 'Main Application'">
  Hello Center!
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is worth researching. *appendChild* method only works with DOM Node. According to the source code, containerNode must be a DOM Node.

dijit/_TemplatedMixin.js

```
 _fillContent: function(/*DomNode*/ source){
    // summary:
    // Relocate source contents to templated container node.
    // this.containerNode must be able to receive children, or exceptions will be thrown.
    // tags:
    // protected
    var dest = this.containerNode;
        if(source && dest){
            while(source.hasChildNodes()){
            dest.appendChild(source.firstChild);
        }
    }
},
```

Look at this dijit/_WidgetBase.js. The comment shows that the type of *containerNode* is *DomNode*.

```
// containerNode: [readonly] DomNode
//      Designates where children of the source DOM node will be placed.
//      "Children" in this case refers to both DOM nodes and widgets.
//      For example, for myWidget:
//
//      |   <div data-dojo-type=myWidget>
//      |       <b> here's a plain DOM node
//      |       <span data-dojo-type=subWidget>and a widget</span>
//      |       <i> and another plain DOM node </i>
//      |   </div>
//
//      containerNode would point to:
//
//      |       <b> here's a plain DOM node
//      |       <span data-dojo-type=subWidget>and a widget</span>
//      |       <i> and another plain DOM node </i>
//
//      In templated widgets, "containerNode" is set via a
//      data-dojo-attach-point assignment.
//
//      containerNode must be defined for any widget that accepts innerHTML
//      (like ContentPane or BorderContainer or even Button), and conversely
//      is null for widgets that don't, like TextBox.
containerNode: null,
```

So, the *containerNode* has been desinged to be a *DomNode*, not a bug. It can't be a widget. Maybe you should try some other ways.

**Update:**
Add some BorderContainers in custom widget

ModuleWithGuideBar.html

```
<div data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" class="${class} ModuleWithGuideBar">
    <div class="ModuleGuideBar"
         data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer"
         data-dojo-props="region:'top', gutters:false"
         data-dojo-attach-point="guideBarFirst">
    </div>
    <div class="ModuleGuideBar"
         data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer"
         data-dojo-props="region:'top', gutters:false"
         data-dojo-attach-point="guideBarSecond">
    </div>
    <div class="ModuleContent"
         data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer"
         data-dojo-props="region:'center', gutters:false, liveSplitters:false"
         data-dojo-attach-point="moduleContent">
    </div>
</div>
```

Js file

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
    "dojo/text!./templates/ModuleWithGuideBar.html"

], function (declare, BorderContainer, TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, template) {
    return declare("common.widget.ModuleWithGuideBar", [BorderContainer, TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
        templateString:template,
        region:"center",
        gutters:false,
        guideBarFirst:null,
        guideBarSecond:null,
        moduleContent:null
    });
});
```

Comment: I got it to work via adding a div with the attachment point, however it doesn't seem to parse the border container correctly. I literally can lift up the template and place it into my file, and it works correctly, but when it parses it, the border container isn't drawn properly. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: Your can mixin dijit/_LayoutWidget, if there are some BorderContainers in custom widget. But you must define your own *layout()* method, to manage the internal BorderContainers. I found a easy way to do this. Look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
define([
//...
    "dijit/_WidgetBase"
```

then

```
return declare('YourWidget',[_WidgetBase , _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin],{
     templatePath: 'local/to/your/template.html',
     widgetsInTemplate: true,
     //...
```

then

```
var yourWidget= new YourWidget({},'YourWidgetNodeId');
```